# Intercoder reliability without mutually-exclusive codes

Tags: agreement-statistics, fuzzy, qualitative, cohens-kappa

I have the results from qualitatively coding the contents of ~100 images, with 7 categories and 96 tags in total. It's incredibly difficult to define mutually exclusive codes for the content we're interested in. For example, we code whether a person is depicted acting as a consumer, as an employee, and/or as a family member. With so many codes, it's a nightmare to define hyper-specific categories that would guarantee mutual exclusivity of every code.

> Q: Are there any methods for estimating inter-rater reliability for data that violates the assumption of mutual exclusivity?

Comment: Loosely related question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/294454/how-to-count-inter-rater-reliability-when-20-mutually-exclusive-categorical-code

Answer (score 1):

Krippendorff (known for his, extremely flexible, inter-rate agreement coefficient) has come up with a proposal on how to measure reliability when raters have
multiple interpretations of the same unit. However, I do not know any statistical package that implements this idea.

Krippendorff, K. (2004). Measuring the Reliability of Qualitative Text Analysis Data. Quality and Quantity, 38 (6), 787-800. https://doi.org/10.1007/s11135-004-8107-7

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that no, there isn't any well-established way of solving this problem. One name for this type of coding is "one-to-many classification".

However, Kirilenko and Svetlana published an article last year on a "fuzzy kappa" that addresses this problem. They also released demonstration software (available as an executable on SourgeForge). That said, I couldn't actually find any papers or projects that actually *used* this test. They do nicely cover the problem of mutually exclusive codes, saying,

> The existing methods of agreement estimation, e.g., Cohen’s kappa, require that coders place each unit of content into one and only one category (one-to-one coding) from the pre-established set of categories. However, in certain data domains (e.g., maps, photographs, databases of texts and images), this requirement seems overly restrictive.

Kirilenko, Andrei P., and Svetlana Stepchenkova. "[Inter-coder agreement in one-to-many classification: Fuzzy kappa.](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0149787)" PloS one 11.3 (2016): e0149787.